# Comparing rows of an R matrix with a predefined vector

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have made a matrix with values 1 and 0, and I want to check if there is one or more rows identical to (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0).

How can I do this?

Here's my code so far for making the matrix:

```
moeda <- c(0, 1)
n <- 100

casosTotais <- 0
casosFav <- 0
caras <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)  ## the vector to compare with

matriz <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = 10)

i <- 1
lin <- 1
col <- 1

while(i <= n * 10){

    matriz[lin, col] <- sample(moeda,1) 
     
    if(col==10){  
        lin <- lin + 1 
        col <- col - 10 
    } 
     
    i <- i + 1 
    col <- col + 1
}

matriz
```

Comment: Hi! Yes, it helped a lot, thank you! The other way to make the matrix you presented is a lot useful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will first assume a general `caras` with zeros and ones:

```
## a vector of TRUE/FALSE; TRUE means a row of `matriz` is identical to `caras`
comp <- colSums(abs(t(matriz) - caras)) == 0
```

Then if `caras` is a simply a vector of zeros:

```
## a vector of TRUE/FALSE; TRUE means a row of `matriz` only contains zeros
comp <- rowSums(matriz) == 0
```

If you want to summarize the comparison:

- To know which rows of `matriz` are identical to `caras`, do `which(comp)`.
- To know if any row of `matriz` is identical to `caras`, do `any(comp)`.
- To know how many rows of `matriz` is identical to `caras`, do `sum(comp)`.

---

**Note:** You can generate this random matrix using:

```
## an n x 10 random matrix of zeros and ones
matriz <- matrix(rbinom(n * 10, size = 1, prob = 0.5), ncol = 10)
```